# Strange lubridate (1.3.3) error in period calculation

Tags: r

```
library(lubridate)
span <- new_interval(dmy("31/10/2002"),dmy("18/07/2005"))
as.period(span,unit="month")$month

Error in while (any(start + est * per > end)) est[start + est * per >  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

What is going wrong here? I have used the same code many times without problem.

Comment: It runs Ok with `lubridate_1.4.0.9000`

Comment: Where can I find it? It's not on CRAN

Comment: Installed from github. `devtools::install_github("hadley/lubridate")`